# how to set item in different users using local storage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

```js
// ! THIS IS FOR SIGN UP PAGE :)
const firstName = document.getElementById("firstName");
const lastnName = document.getElementById("lastName");
const email = document.getElementById("newEmail");
const password = document.getElementById("newPassword");

const btnSignup = document.getElementById("btn-signup");

function signUp() { // when mouse click "signup" button
  const first_name = firstName.value; // getting the value of firstName and so on..
  const last_name = lastName.value;
  const e_mail = newEmail.value;
  const pass_word = newPassword.value;

  // if the fields are empty
  if (!first_name || !last_name || !e_mail || !pass_word) {
    return alert("you need to fill up all the forms.");
  }
  //set user input into JSON
  let user_data = {
    firstName: first_name,
    lastName: last_name,
    email: e_mail,
    password: pass_word
  }

  //convert to string
  let user_data_str = JSON.stringify(user_data);

  //get to localstorage if there is existing user ||or make empty array[]
  let clientsArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users')) || [];

  // search the list if
  const userExists = clientsArr.find(user => JSON.stringify(user) === user_data_str);
  if (userExists) {
    return alert("User already Exists");
  }

  //push new user to array
  clientsArr.push(user_data);

  //save to localStorage
  localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify(clientsArr));
  return alert("Account Created!");

}

btnSignup.addEventListener("click", signUp);
```

this is my functioning code in localStorage(to do list), how can I input different "to do" with different user without changing each other data inside them.?it's tricky for me because I made different users inside the localStorage.

example:

user1 : to do list 1
user2 : to do list 2
user3 : to do list 3

thanks in advance.!

Comment: What do you mean by `without changing each other data inside them`?

Comment: What I mean is, one set of to do list in one user, meaning: the other user cannot change what's in the local storage.

"the application should support as many unique users as possible. The actions that one user takes within the application should have virtually no effect on what other users are doing."

Comment: @Patrick Did you get this to work with your todo list for different users? I am looking to implement something similar in LocalStorage with a customer list. I need each user to have his own list that doesn't affect the other users list.

Answer (score 0):

You will need some unique identifier to differentiate between users. You can get that identifier by making a required input or even better, from your backend if you have one. With a unique identifier you then just change your `.find()` method to search for the ID.

Another option would be to use a different subdomain for each user. With each subdomain you get a separate `localStorage`. But this option may not make sense for your case, it depends on what you want. I just wanted to list the option.